# Magnetic flux quantisation in ring superconductor

Tags: superconductivity

My book says ,flux quantisation is consequence of phase relationship of wave function of electrons in presence of magnetic field. This is based on effect of magnetic vector potential on wave function. I am not able to understand this. Help me to understand this or any other explanation of flux quantisation if you can give.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the flux quantization is due to the **energy** minimization.

Imagine we have a superconducting ring, with radius $R_0$, and let's use the Ginzburg-Landau's description where the order parameter $\psi(\theta)$ ( here the radius has been fixed ) plays the role of two-particle centre of mass wavefuncton. We can write down the Schrodinger equation in the ring ( in polar axis ):

$$\frac{1}{2m^*}\left( \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{1}{R_0} \partial_{\theta}+2eA  \right)^2\psi=E \psi$$

here we have assumed that the vector potential $A$ inside the ring is the same as the external potential which is a constant along the ring, and notice the charge of the "particle" is $-2e$.

One can check that the solution of $\psi$ is like:

$\psi(\theta) \sim e^{in\theta}$ ( n $\in \mathbb{Z}$ which is due to the periodic boundary condition )

and the kinetic energy is:

$$\begin{align}
E_K &= \frac{1}{2m^*}\left( \frac{\hbar}{R_0}n+2eA\right)^2 \\
  &= \frac{\hbar^2}{2m^* R_0^2}\left( n+\frac{\phi}{\phi_0} \right)^2
\end{align}$$

here the $\phi = 2\pi R_0 A$, $\phi_0 = \frac{h}{2e}$.

From this simple calculation, we can now see that one can add $\textbf{whatever}$ value of flux through the ring, but the minimal eigenvalue is give by the eigenstate where $n+\frac{\phi}{\phi_0}$ is closest to zero. Of course, when the flux is quantised ( $\frac{\phi}{\phi_0}\in \mathbb{Z}$ ), the minimum eigenenergy would be 0, which is favored.

One of the most well-known effects rely on this fact is the [Little-Park effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%E2%80%93Parks_effect).

Comment: This should be an accepted answer IMO